Statistically determining a count of particles
I perform experiments to do measurements on various pharmaceuticals. One such measurement is interested in the number of particles which is confined into a small volume.
The raw data in my experiment is a video of size 32 x 32 pixels, which has higher background noise, and contains multiple particles randomly diffusing. Then, I track the particles using a local maxima track.
The tracking method produces the following set of information:
$$\vec p = \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \text{mass}
\\\ \text{ecc}\\ \text{raw_mass} \end{bmatrix}$$
where x,y are the positions, mass, raw_mass are the intensity of the particle (integrated around a chosen radius $r$. ecc (eccentricity) denotes the circularity of the particle.
Now, the statistical question arises. Given a set of $N$ particle measurements in a single image/frame, I am having a hard time to statistically form a way to determine what is the probability of there being $N$ particles. For instance, there could be noise, which influences the decision of the count, or there could be a clumping of particles.
In short, given an image and a algorithmically determined set of vectors $\vec p$, what is the probability that each measurement truly reflects a particle, as well as, what is the confidence of this measurement.
Attempted Ideas
1.
In terms of determining if there is a particle or not, there must be a way to compare the neighbouring intensities against the particle. Ie, the particle should have significantly more signal than that of the background/missed detection.
2.
I have also tried brainstorming how to create a way to tune a set of parameters to statistically infer this decision. Ie, let a threshold determine an infimum which allows the least bright particle be distinguished. This needs to be dynamically done as each training set is supposed to be very large. Due to the nature of the experiment (fluorescent labelling), there are physical limits to this as well
Please let me know if there are any statistical references/advice that can help me start this problem.
ps: Tags are chosen as I think they should be, let me know if there is anything that I should change.
